# Best way to rank order and display posts based on connections/friends using NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am working on an app which uses NEO4J. There are mainly two types of Nodes

1. User - User nodes can be connected among each other with relationship 'FRIENDS'
2. Post - Posts nodes consists of posts created by the users and has a relationship of 'OWNED_BY' between user who created the post and the actual post node

For example,

1. Consider there are 3 users A,B,C and 4 posts B1,B2 (from user B) and C1,C2 (from user C)
2. A and B are connected with 'FRIENDS'
3. For user A the post display order should be B1,B2,C1,C2 on his/her dashboard ( i.e. we should display the posts which are created by the immediate network followed by posts which are not from his/her network)

Need some guidance on how this can be achieved using CYPHER query

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you get an error on your query? What is the error? What is the expected result?

Comment: MATCH(n:User)-[r:FRIENDS_WITH]-(u1:User) where n.name = 'A'
with u1
match(s:Post)-[r1:OWNED_BY]-(u1)
UNION
(Trying to figure out how to select Post which are not in s )

I'm trying to address based on my SQL knowledge. I'm getting posts of all users who are FRIENDS_WITH 'A' and after this I want to do a UNION of missing posts, but unable to figure this out